# Photoshop Script change each successive image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a script that batch processes images, adding a radial blur on the blue channel. 
What I want to do is change the radial blur's origin or centre point in each successive image. Is there a way of scripting this? 
At the moment for the first image, when I recorded the action, i placed the centre point manually, photoshop must have some code somewhere to show what I did. Any ideas on how to access this?

It's a series of the sun shining through trees, I want the radial blur to track from one side to the other like the sun does in the images (timelapse)

Comment: Based on the [photshop cc javascript reference pdf](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) I'd say no. Not directly anyways. Example code says:  `applyRadialBlur(amount, blurMethod, blurQuality)` None of these three arguments control the location. **|||** You could perhaps get around it by adding extra whitespace to the document before applying the radial blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of automation control isn't really available using just Photoshop actions, to go that deep you'll need to leverage [Photoshop's Scripting API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge on the PS API; I'd recommend visiting [ps-scripts.com](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/), hopefully you can find some experts there.